# Discord.js DM a member when they are muted

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am making a kick command for my bot, and it works well, but I also wanted it to DM the person who was kicked. I have mentioned member to mean the person you intend to ban, and this is my code after they are kicked:

```js
msg.mentionedMember.send(‘You were kicked from ${guild.name} ${reason ? ‘for **${reason}**’ : ‘’}’);
```

When I run this, it says “Cannot read property ‘send’ of undefined”

What should I correct about this?

Comment: Please could you provide us with a bit more of your code?

Comment: Just send the message before you kick them; the member becomes undefined when you kick I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have mentionedMember defined? if not, do:

```
var mentionedMember = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
```

Then, all you need to do DM the mentioned user is:

```
mentionedMember.send(`You were kicked!`);
```